# Gradle sais that the return statment of onStartCommmand is unreachable

Tags: android, gradle, service, build

Hey guys this is the code of my onStartFunction command in service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startid)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startid);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        for(;;) {
            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = ((UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE));
            for (UsageStats usageStats : usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, current - 1000, current)) {
                Log.i("Nome processo", usageStats.getPackageName());
            }
        }


        return 0;

    }
```

The problem is when i'm compile it because gradle says to me that the return 0 is an "Error:(56, 9) error: unreachable statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a for loop with no parameters.  That is an infinite loop.  You need some way for the loop to terminate or the return statement will never be reached.